# jquery.animate has delay in 2 loops

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, delay

I am writing animation on jquery: there 11+ pictures and they move left on page through 2 loops / cycles (`for`).

**Question:** After first cycle (where `j`) animation has delay ~1 sec and then all 11 pictures move on 50px again. then again ~1 sec and again move. so there are 11 delays, as `var i = [0..10]`. How to remove this delay? From where does it rise? I need to move in 2 loops pictures smoothly and fluently every iteration.

p.s. i need 2 loops for my aims

```
$('.movePics').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            var r = j + i;
            if (r == i) {
                $('ul li:eq('+r+')').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 600);
            } else {
                $('ul li:eq('+r+')').animate({"left": "-=50px"}, 600);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HERE is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zyMXx/

Comment: `"left": "-=50px"` I think this will not work.

Comment: everything works, but there are only delay between each 11 iterations

Comment: What's the purpose of the `.hide()`? Your description only talks about moving the images, not hiding them. Could you please provide a demo? I've copied your JS into JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hb2Wb/ - could you please add the relevant html and CSS to make it work to show us what you're talking about?

Comment: thank you for answering. i created jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zyMXx/